# How to show the date format from .ts class to .html in angular 7?

Tags: angular

I am getting the data from API as `childDob: "23/10/2019"` how to show this in .html 
here is my frontend code is

```
<input type="date" [(ngModel)]="allUpdate.childDob" required>
```

How to do this? Any help.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with date pipe like :

```html
<input type="date" [(ngModel)]="allUpdate.childDob | date: 'M/d/yy'" required>
```

For more details : https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe